# Provide and prove a lower bound on the area of h.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Suppose $h$ is a complex valued holomorphic, injective function from the unit disc such that $h'(0)=1$ in particular. Provide and prove a lower bound on the area of $im(h)=h(D)$.

I have been unable to make any progress on this, despite a hint from a classmate to use $\pi$ as a lower bound. Can someone please explain how to tackle this question? I am currently learning complex integration and I'm allowed to use Cauchys Theorem and Integral formula. However we have not learned anything about "residues" yet.

Comment: use the area integral formula $\int\int_D |h'(z)|^2dxdy$, then polar coordinates and expand $|h'(z)|^2=h'(z)\bar h'(z)$ in terms of $h(z)=\sum a_nz^n$; the diagonal terms cancel when integrated $d\theta$ and one gets the area formula in terms of the $a_n, n \ge 1$ (useful to do it first by yourself!) ; the formula starts with $\pi |a_1|^2=\pi$ and only adds non negative terms so one gets the lower bound $\pi$ with equality iff $h(z)=z$

Comment: @Conrad can you please link me a page to read up on this area integral formula for complex numbers? I can’t find it in my book so I imagine the teacher was going to give it in a future lecture but I’d like to learn about it sooner than a week from now

Comment: this is just the usual change of variables from two-dimensional calculus using the (determinant of the) Jacobian of $h$ as a map from the plane to itself; by Cauchy Riemann, the determinant of the Jacobian is just $|h'(z)|^2$; any text of complex analysis should have this among its introductroy stuff